# Q: SQLite query to find islands in data (that is, sequential rows where a value has met a certain threshold)

Tags: sqlite, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a SQLite database with, let's say, the percentage of dead cells found in a cancerous organism over time (NOTE: the time column values were changed to simple numbers for readability).

```
id  time                deadcellspercent
1   000000001000000000  35
2   000000002000000000  54
3   000000003000000000  31
4   000000004000000000  15
5   000000005000000000  38
6   000000006000000000  70
7   000000007000000000  28
8   000000008000000000  13
9   000000009000000000  99
10  000000010000000000  51
```

I want to create a SQLite query that will return a range of the times where the percentage fell above a certain threshold number.  For example, if I say I want the threshold to be >= 20, then the query result should return:

```
ts_start            ts_end
000000001000000000  000000003000000000
000000005000000000  000000007000000000
000000009000000000  000000010000000000
```

How do I form the query to do this?  I read up on topics such as "SQLite window functions", the "gaps and islands problem", and "analytic functions", but I am an SQL novice and couldn't make heads or tails of it to get the desired result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-between/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on a right track with window functions and gaps and islands.

First, let's take your sample data and populate a table with it:

```
CREATE TABLE cells(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time TEXT, deadcellspercent INTEGER);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(1,'000000001000000000',35);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(2,'000000002000000000',54);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(3,'000000003000000000',31);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(4,'000000004000000000',15);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(5,'000000005000000000',38);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(6,'000000006000000000',70);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(7,'000000007000000000',28);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(8,'000000008000000000',13);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(9,'000000009000000000',99);
INSERT INTO cells VALUES(10,'000000010000000000',51);
```

One possible query (Which uses window functions and thus requires an up to date version of sqlite - 3.25 or newer):

```
WITH islands AS (SELECT id, time
                      , row_number() OVER w1 - row_number() OVER w2 AS diff
                      , deadcellspercent >= 20 AS wanted
                 FROM cells
                 WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY time)
                      , w2 AS (PARTITION BY deadcellspercent >= 20 ORDER BY time))
SELECT min(time) AS ts_start, max(time) AS ts_end
FROM islands
WHERE wanted = 1
GROUP BY diff
ORDER BY diff;
```

produces:

```
ts_start            ts_end            
------------------  ------------------
000000001000000000  000000003000000000
000000005000000000  000000007000000000
000000009000000000  000000010000000000
```

(Heavily influenced by [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167068/solving-gaps-and-islands-with-row-number-and-dense-rank) on the DBA stackexchange; refer to it for explanations).

Comment: This is great!  Turns out my problem was that I was using the latest official release of SQLite DB Browser app (v 3.10.1), which was NOT up-to-date with the latest underlying SQLite 3.25+ version.  I downloaded their nightly build version and it seems to handle the window functions now!  Thank you very much, and I will be studying every line of this query to understand it.